# Why do comments remain in pending status?

Tags: express, microservices

I developed a microservice application for a small blog application. It has a post service, a comment service, a query service and a moderation service.

The moderation service is responsible for moderating and filtering out certain comments and approving others:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/events", async (req, res) => {
  const { type, data } = req.body;

  if (type === "CommentCreated") {
    const status = /cdc/gi.test(data.content) ? "rejected" : "approved";

    await axios.post("http://localhost:4005/events", {
      type: "CommentModerated",
      data: {
        id: data.id,
        postId: data.postId,
        status,
        content: data.content,
      },
    });
  }

  res.send({});
});

app.listen(4003, () => {
  console.log("Listening on 4003");
});
```

During some manual testing, I shut down the query service and created a post with comments with the expectation that once query service came back online, it would receive the events of post and comments created from the event bus and the user would be able to see the moderated comments, that is those that were approved and rejected, but I believe I introduced a bug in my application by defaulting the status of the comments to pending in the comments service like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { randomBytes } = require("crypto");
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const commentsByPostId = {};

app.get("/posts/:id/comments", (req, res) => {
  res.send(commentsByPostId[req.params.id] || []);
});

app.post("/posts/:id/comments", async (req, res) => {
  const commentId = randomBytes(4).toString("hex");
  const { content } = req.body;

  const comments = commentsByPostId[req.params.id] || [];

  comments.push({ id: commentId, content, status: "pending" });

  commentsByPostId[req.params.id] = comments;

  await axios.post("http://localhost:4005/events", {
    type: "CommentCreated",
    data: { id: commentId, content, postId: req.params.id, status: "pending" },
  });

  res.status(201).send(comments);
});

app.post("/events", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Event Received:", req.body.type);

  const { type, data } = req.body;

  if (type === "CommentModerated") {
    const { id, postId, status, content } = data;
    const comments = commentsByPostId[postId];

    const comment = comments.find((comment) => {
      return comment.id === id;
    });
    comment.status = status;

    await axios.post("http://localhost:4005/events", {
      type: "CommentUpdated",
      data: {
        id,
        content,
        postId,
        status,
      },
    });
  }

  res.send({});
});
```

I am unclear how to get out of this corner I painted myself in with making the `status: 'pending'` be the default behavior as I did not expect that it would stay stuck in this default behavior when a microservice came back online from being crashed or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in my event bus, because I kept getting Unhandled Promise Rejections earlier in my event bus terminal I thought I had to add `async/await` syntax in there like so:

```
app.post("/events", async (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;

  events.push(event);

  await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/events", event);
  await axios.post("http://localhost:4001/events", event);
  await axios.post("http://localhost:4002/events", event);
  await axios.post("http://localhost:4003/events", event);

  res.send({ status: "OK" });
});
```

But in the end I realized that I was still getting unhandled promise rejections in my event bus terminal and it was not affecting anything else and initially I did not think the above was an asynchronous operation to begin with.

So after studying all the code closely including the frontend codebase, I decided on a hunch to just go back to event bus and remove the `async/await` syntax and sure enough, while the query service was down I was able to submit comments and when the query service came back online it received not only the `CommentCreated` events but also the `CommentModerated` and `CommentUpdated` events.

So this is what it should look like:

```
app.post("/events", (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;

  events.push(event);

  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/events", event);
  axios.post("http://localhost:4001/events", event);
  axios.post("http://localhost:4002/events", event);
  axios.post("http://localhost:4003/events", event);

  res.send({ status: "OK" });
});
```